# jQuery split get last 2 digit

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
'2018-12-2417:25:33'.split('-');
```

Outptut:

```
["2018", "12", "2417:25:33"]
```

Expected Output:

```
["2018", "12", "24"]
```

Can anyone please tell me How can I achieve my expected output?

Comment: Could you possibly provide more code, i.e. how are you generating/getting the string ```2018-12-2417:25:33```? By the looks of it, if it's via using the ```Date``` class, you could use a neater method...

Comment: I believe the expected output to be `["2018", "12", "2417"]`

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with a regex pattern `/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/` and than split with `-`.

```js
let str = "2018-12-2417:25:33"

let op = str.match(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)[0].split('-')

console.log(op);
```

I assume you want to match standard format like `1111-11-11` if not than you can replace the above regex with this `\d+-\d+-\d{1,2}`

Comment: Way smarter approach, just ensure that the format will always be 4d-2d-2d, otherwise you may handle cases like: 2018-1-24 or 2018-12-1 or 2018-1-1 . Not sure how the original format is, but that's likely the cleverest approach for that case specifically.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = '2018-12-2417:25:33'.split('-');
var result = a[0]+'-'+a[1]+'-'+a[2].substring(0, 2);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code works as you have requested, assuming that you have somehow mashed a date and a time code together... and therefore the timecode will also have 8 characters.

I would have a look at how you have created this string, you should really be able to split the date and time values from each other earlier in your code and avoid this nasty hack.

---

## Demo

```js
$(document).on("change keyup paste click", "#dateTime", function() {

  var dateTime = $(this).val();

  // Split on '-'
  var el = dateTime.split('-');

  // Remove the time - we know rimes will always be entered as 'xx:xx:xx' - i.e. 8 characters
  el[2] = el[2].substring(0, el[2].length - 8);

  // Print to console
  $("#dateOutput").text( el );

});

$("#dateTime").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>You can test out the function below</p>
<p>Remember that it expects an eight character time string at the end of the string</p>
<input id="dateTime" value="2018-12-2417:25:33">
<p id="dateOutput"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var date = '2018-12-2417:25:33'.split(':');
date[0].split('-');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could slice the relevant part first and then split the string into parts.

```js
var string = '2018-12-2417:25:33',
    result = string.slice(0, 10).split('-');

console.log(result);
```